# How to remove json format from Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 respond_to do |format|  
      format.html{render :json => {:message => "Success! Check your email to confirm sign up."}}
    end
```

Currently the output is: "{"message":"Success! Check your email to confirm sign up."}"
But i want only as a output: "Success! Check your email to confirm sign up."

Answer (score 0):

```
respond_to do |format|  
  format.html{ render plain: "Success! Check your email to confirm sign up." }
end
```

Although you should most likely be rendering a view instead.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

this is another way......

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html.any   { render text: "Success! Check your email to confirm sign up."   }
end
```